# OMNET send messages

Tags: c++, omnet++

I´m trying to integrate one program to OMNET and send messages from a method created in a specific class. This method calls another method inside a Module.
The follwing code describes what I´m trying to do.

```
    #include "Txcc.h"

    Define_Module(Txcc);
 Txcc::Txcc() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

 } 

Txcc::~Txcc() {
// TODO Auto-generated destructor stub

  }

void Txcc::initialize()
{
// Am I tuc
ev << "XXXXX  INITILIZING XXXXX\n";


  }

 void Txcc::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
 {
    ev << " message received " << endl;

  }

    void Txcc::finish() {
    printf("%s\n", " finishing ....");

  }

   // -----------------------------------------------------
   void Txcc::submitMessageQueue() {

     printf("%s\n", "***************************");
      printf("%s\n", "Message submitted ...");
       printf("%s\n", "***************************");
    cMessage *Mess = new cMessage();
cSimpleModule::send(Mess,"out");

   }
     // --------------------------------------------------------
```

The piece of code that calls submitMessageQueue is:
    .....
       Txcc Transmitter;
        Transmitter.submitMessageQueue();

When this method is called , simulation crashes with the follwing message:

Error at event #1, t=0: (Txcc): no such gate or gate vector: `out'.

TRAPPING on the exception above, due to a debug-on-errors=true configuration option. Is your debugger ready?
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cRuntimeError'
  what():  send()/sendDelayed(): (Txcc): no such gate or gate vector: `out'

Simulation terminated with exit code: 134

Can anyone help me with some information on how to fix it ?

Sincerely,
Andre

Answer (score 0):

Is your Txcc ned file exist the output gate named out?

like

```
simple Txcc{
    gate:
        output out;
}
```

make sure that the ned file exist the correspond output gate you named, when you use `send()`.